# Python and nfqueue error

Tags: python

I'm trying a python script downloaded from a blog to send fake echo-replies after a ping from a machine.
The problem is that when I run the script, it gives me this error:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nfqueue.py", line 96, in
>   create_queue  def create_queue(self,*args): return
>   _nfqueue.queue_create_queue(self, *args) RuntimeError: error during nfq_create_queue()

This is the part where it binds the queue:

```
    import nfqueue

q = None

q = nfqueue.queue()
q.open()
q.bind(socket.AF_INET)
q.set_callback(cb)
q.create_queue(0) 

try:
        q.try_run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Exiting..." 

q.unbind(socket.AF_INET)
q.close()
```

The error is on the q.create_queue(0), but I don't know what to do!

Answer (score 3):

The obtained message may derive from an already running execution of your python script.

Assuming your script file is `pyscriptname.py`, run the following command to check if another instance of your script is already running:

```
ps -aux | grep "pyscriptname.py" | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

In case something returned value is greater than `0`, you can solve the issue by running the following command:

```
kill -9 `ps aux | grep "pyscriptname.py" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Then, you can run again your python script:

```
python pyscriptname.py
```

Comment: Same problem here and no other copies of the script are running.

Answer (score 0):

nfqueue needs root privileges. So run the script as root or run it under sudo